# how to draw rectangle on texture2D Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I want to paint a rectangle on mesh perfectly where I click.
I am taking mouse on texture position using raycast hit.textureCoord. I am storing two points - left down corner and right up corner.

I am trying to paint rectangle using:

```
for (int y = (int)yStartCorner; y < yEndCorner; y++)
{
    for (int x = (int)xStartCorner; x < xEndCorner; x++)
    {
         texture.SetPixel(x, y, Color.black);
     }
}
texture.Apply();
```

But it's problem with precision. When I am changing float textureCoord to int, I lost data and my rectangle isn't perfectly in places I clicked.

Any ideas how to do it better? Maybe not with loops or maybe I should count something more?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you first taking pixel int coordinate from hit.textureCoord? like here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html

Answer (score 0):

```
(int)yStartCorner
```

parses the `float` to `int` by just cutting of anything after the comma.

You should get a bit more accurate results using e.g. [`Mathf.RoundToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.RoundToInt.html)

```
Mathf.RoundToInt(yStartCorner)
```

which now correctly rounds up (`> x,5`) or down (`< x,5`).

> If the number ends in .5 so it is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, the even number is returned.